# Python3 estrange behaviour of input()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I like to train for contest programming, where the input consists of multiple lines, for example (from https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/equilibrium-point/0)

```
2
1
1
5
1 3 5 2 2
```

I coded:

```
textIn = input()
print(textIn)
```

The output in Python console only capture the first line. I installed Pycharm and the same happens, except when I choose "Run with Python console" and the input captured is:

```
'2\n1\n1\n5\n1 3 5 2 2'
```

Which is easily separable for my purposes, but why is this difference. Finally I installed Spyder and it directly captures  as '2\n1\n1\n5\n1 3 5 2 2' too.

I ask what is the best way to process a multiple line input and which I should use to code?

Comment: try `print(repr(textIn))` for the string *representation*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the amount of lines of input, or this is received as the first input, you could use:

```
n = int(input().strip()) #Replace with number of lines of input if known
a= []

for _ in range(n):
    a.append(input().strip())
```

Comment: Although I was thinking in a general solution to the input and next parse it, I will adapt your proposal. Thanks.